# Fail to decorate - Sonar Analysis

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner

I am facing an issue when trying to run the sonar analysis. It is failing with the following exception

```
Caused by: org.sonar.api.utils.SonarException: Fail to decorate 'org.sonar.api.resources.File@4959e9b7[key=src/main/java/com/mycompany/myproject/common/entities/beans/CountryBean.java,deprecatedKey=com.mycompany.myproject.common.entities.beans.CountryBean,path=src/main/java/com/mycompany/myproject/common/entities/beans/CountryBean.java,dir=com/mycompany/myproject/common/entities/beans,filename=CountryBean.java,language=Java]' at     org.sonar.batch.phases.DecoratorsExecutor.executeDecorator(DecoratorsExecutor.java:103)
```

The complete error stack trace is http://pastebin.com/zuTH61q9

How do I fix this issue? I have another project which is working fine without any error with the same configuration.

My sonarqube version is 5.0

Comment: I think you have too long paths. If you are using windows, then this can be a problem. Try to move your project into the root or somewhere else and try to run it again.

Comment: Changing the path did not solve the issue. I copied my code to a shorter path and still I have the same problem. I have issues only with one file and if I delete that file, I am able to complete the analysis without any issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could fix the issue by deleting the java file and create a new file with the same contents.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommand that you publish the whole log, so that people may know which plugins you are using and help you find the source of this error.

Also, if you could explain a little bit the organization of your analysis because the problem could come from, for example, duplicated files.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I've noticed is that sometimes IDE or text editors will change the code structure from multi-line to one-line. Having a really long string will cause SonarQube to fail with the same error message. Double check your code to make sure it is still structured properly.